# Java in browser: application blocked (multiple domains)

Tags: security, java-applet

Java made me to update to the latest version and now I get the "Application Blocked" error all the time. Alright, I have lowered the security (although it only allows for the "medium" level, omg), and added the site to the exceptions, but now, I get a more specific error:

[image]

I need to be able to run the sketches (java applets) from the openprocessing site, but half of them fails with this error.. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3):

Java has tried very hard to turn out a safe platform, thus breaking just about everything.

Java does have various [steps to try and resolve:](http://java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml)

> WORKAROUND
>
> [snip]
>
> If the URL where the applet is hosted is different from the URL of the
>   web page from which the applet is launched, then you will need to add
>   both the URL for the applet as well as the URL for the web page.
>
> Example with different URLs for the applet and the web page For Yahoo
>   games Checkers, you would enter both URLs (The urls listed can be
>   different depending on which host is serving the game)
>   http://www.games.yahoo.com This is the url for the Yahoo games domain
>   http://yog36.games.sp2.yahoo.com This is the url where the game is
>   hosted and shown in the dialog box for the blocked application
>
> [snip]

Comment: But omg, the referred domain name looks like it is programmatically generated at the first level! (i.e. http://c0392967.. ) and it really is! I have just checked it out... man, I gonna cry.. :(